# Weird space at the top in firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I'm working on a ticket system for my website and I have this unusual space at the top of the page for some reason in firefox, but not in chrome, opera, safari, or IE. Just firefox. Anyone know why?
Url:http://beta.campatet.com/tickets/

Check images below:
Chrome:
[image: Chrome]
Firefox:
[image]

Comment: did you try inspecting this with firebug?

Comment: nope, I'm going to try that now

Comment: change margin to: <body style="margin: 0 0 0 0px;" >

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `h1` element is pushing the header down. Try adding `clear: both;` to the `h1` element's css.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing your floats. (ul, li)

```
<h1 style='clear:both'></h1>
```